# Facts not updated on puppetboard

Tags: puppet

Facts are not updated by applying new timezone Europe/Berlin. Puppetboard shows old value.
It always shows UTC instead of CEST.

Role `class profile::timezone` was correctly applied and `facter -y` shows CEST, but in puppetboard is still UTC.
After applying `puppet agent -t` facts were correctly updated.

Role:

```
class profile::timezone {
  class { 'timezone':
    timezone => 'Europe/Berlin',
  }
}
```

**puppet master version 6.6.0**

**puppet agent version 6.2.0**

Expected value is CEST when new role is applied. So is not necessary to do it manually by `puppet agent -t`.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why timezone fact was not updated? Anyway, it`s solved by update to puppet version 6.8.0